# View.py changes not updating on Django site

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, raspberry-pi

New Django user. Hello world. Got it to work. "Hello, world!" in the browser.

I went back into views.py and updated the line to read "Hello, world! You're at the index." and saved it. Refreshing the browser (F5) does not show the change. Even Ctrl-F5 doesn't refresh it.

I'm running `./manage.py runserver`, and it recognizes that the file was changed and reloads the site:

```
/home/pi/pidjango/doorbell/views.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 14, 2021 - 14:00:19
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'pidjango.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But refreshing the browser still shows the old line. I have to reboot the computer in order to see the change. But it does change, so I know the file is the correct one in the correct spot.

I'm not even sure what this is called. It's some kind of cache that's not flushing, so I researched Django caching and couldn't find anything that helped. I'm running '''DEBUG = True''', so you'd think this would be a pretty common thing to do.

This is on a headless Raspberry Pi, connected by SSH, so there's no local browser to try. I'm accessing it from the local network.

Comment: please add template and views

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was not using the Django server. I was using Apache2 on the Raspberry Pi. I should have known, since I was accessing the site at port 80.

Anyway, it works fine. Just need to restart Apache when the page is not refreshing.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```